# How I can collapse all collections except non excluded ones?

Tags: scripting

I got this script working which will collapse all collections in the `View Layer`

```
def toggle_collection_collapse():
    area = next(a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type == 'OUTLINER')
    with bpy.context.temp_override(**bpy.context.copy()):
        bpy.ops.outliner.show_hierarchy({'area': area}, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        bpy.ops.outliner.expanded_toggle({'area': area})
        bpy.ops.outliner.expanded_toggle({'area': area})
    area.tag_redraw()
```

Now what I will like is to collapse collections that are not excluded with the checkbox

[image]

So for example the collection `trees` should be collapsed but the `flowers` collection not

I looked at the blender API and I can't find how to just collapse a single collection, only all of them at the same time.

I am missing something?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to specify which collection to collapse or expand.